# iOS screenshot live camera preview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, camera, screenshot

I have live camera in my app (in scrollView) and for transition I need to take screenshot of camera preview and get that image, but

```
 drawHierarchy(in rect: CGRect,afterScreenUpdates afterUpdates: Bool)
```

method doesn't help. Is there a way to achieve this without OpenGL. Please help, cause it's already several days I am searching the solution.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((self.getRectOfSceneInScrollView(index: self.selectedSceneIndex!).size), false, 0);
self.scrollView.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect.init(--some rect--), afterScreenUpdates: true)

let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!;

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

UPDATE:
self.scrollView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!) doesn't help too

Answer (score 1):

Apple has some restrictions on capturing the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` from our custom camera view by using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`. Even `UIView` Snapchat method will not work if we have camera view.

But we do have a workaround to get the effect. Get the image buffer for each camera frame and convert it to `UIImage`. Add the image to our screenshot manually. It's not that simple and AFAIK this is the best workaround. More info can be found in SO Answer from [Is it possible to render AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in a graphics context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012397/is-it-possible-to-render-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-in-a-graphics-context)

Comment: Thank You @Bluewings for answer, it could be helpful, but the problem is that I want that screenshot not only during or after capturing, I need it after a button click for example, for transitions and animations, that's the problem

Comment: If you want to get an image and use it for transitions, the only way i can think of is taking pictures from live camera and use it for transitions and animations

Answer (score -2):

```
func takeScreenshot(view: UIView) -> UIImageView {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
        view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

        return UIImageView(image: image)
    }
```

Comment: thanks BHAVIK PANCHAL, but this doesn't help, I only get white photo

Comment: i will see if any solution then reply you